# Getting org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton error after upgrading from Spring Security 2.0.2 to 3.2.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, maven-3, aspectj-maven-plugin

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.6:compile (default) on project services: Compiler errors:
error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=2845 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.CompilationFailedException: Compiler errors:
error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=2845 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

Below is the pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT
    jar
    CFT services layer

```
<prerequisites>
    <maven>2.2.1</maven>
</prerequisites>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Finxera</id>
        <name>Finxera Repo</name>
        <url>http://10.10.200.125:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <!-- enable filtering on the CPIISRV-revision.properties -->
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/CPIISERVICES-revision.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <!--enable resourcing in resources folder for all the properties files -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.0.1</version> -->
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--This plugin increase the size of maven memory -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                <useFullNames>false</useFullNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.5</version> -->
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade begins -->

                <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId> 
                    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId> <version>1.8.1</version> </dependency> -->

                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api -->
                <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId> <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId> 
                    <version>1.2</version> </dependency> -->

                <!-- Added for Stack Upgrade ends -->
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!--<groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.1.1</version> -->
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <!-- <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.6</version> -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kyc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>net.nationalpayment.core.services.external.exp</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/kyc/</schemaDirectory>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/kyc</generateDirectory>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${jdbc.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${jdbc.artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.0.2</version> -->
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <current.build.version>versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT</current.build.version>
    <!-- Application settings -->
    <dao.framework>hibernate</dao.framework>
    <web.framework>spring</web.framework>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <commons.fileupload.version>1.2.1</commons.fileupload.version>
    <commons.io.version>1.3.2</commons.io.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>

    <springmodules.validation.version>0.8</springmodules.validation.version>
</properties>
```

Output of mvn dependency:tree. Could not paste entire out due to text length constraint. Removed all messages related to download and downloaded. Please bear with me as i am new to maven.

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro-2:services vimal$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] net.nationalpayment.cp20:services:jar:versionUpgrade-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.cache:cache-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.28:compile
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.4:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.8:runtime
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.docx4j:docx4j:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-svg11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xslfo:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.plutext:jaxb-xmldsig-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.engio:mbassador:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.arnx:wmf2svg:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.finxera:FinxeraEncryptionUtility:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codedeploy:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-config:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecs:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-workspaces:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-machinelearning:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.9.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jamonapi:jamon:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.nationalpayment.sml:sml-framework:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.nationalpayment.sml:sml-model:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.legsem.legstar:legstar-coxbapi:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.legsem.legstar:legstar-coxbrt:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- bai-parser:bai-parser:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-api:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svnexe:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-provider-svn-commons:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- regexp:regexp:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.49:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.ostermiller:utils:jar:1.07.00:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-js:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.0-beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-api:jar:1.0M8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-impl-dom:jar:1.0M8:compile
[INFO] |  +- annogen:annogen:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.castor:spring-xml:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jxls:jxls-core:jar:1.0-RC-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.cdgsoftware:x937-BBX:jar:0.1.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.bancbox.payment21:bancbox-payment21:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
[INFO] |              \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
[INFO] +- com.paypal:paypal_stubs:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.paypal:paypal_base:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.bancbox:generate-key:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:jar:2.46.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.chrislaforetsoftware:fedwireparser:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.litle:litle-sdk-for-java:jar:8.17.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml:jsr173:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.ffpojo:ffpojo:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- au.com.bytecode:opencsv:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  \- junit-addons:junit-addons:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- geronimo-spec:geronimo-spec-jta:jar:1.0.1B-rc4:provided
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- de.odysseus.staxon:staxon:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.4.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] Total time: 2:08.333s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 30 12:11:28 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/200M
```

I am using Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the following process > Right click project > Run As > Maven Clean. Right Click > Maven > Update Project > Check Mark force update of snapshot option. And finally Right Click > Run As > Maven Install.

Comment: Tried this.But no luck. But Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartInitializingSingleton may require newer version of Spring than the version, which is in your pom:

```
<version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
```

Try:

```
<version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
```

You may be also mising various versions of Spring in your pom file. Put the same version in all Spring dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i am already on this version of Spring ORM AOP, JDBC, ASPECT and Context Support(4.2.3.RELEASE).                 Did you mean i need to upgrade to Spring Security to      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId> <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version> ?

Comment: Please paste the whole pom file and preferably the mvn dependency:tree command output.

Comment: Provided whole pom file and the output of mvn dependency:tree

Answer (score 2):

**Recommended Options**

1. Go to [spring boot initializr](https://start.spring.io/) site, select spring security stack as shown in below [image: figure] and generate the sample application/pom file and refactor your dependencies accordingly.
2. As spring-boot uses the concept of **opinionated dependencies and Bill of Materials**, it will pull up your appropriate version of your dependencies which will resolve your jar conflict.

Comment: Thanks. But it did not help.